# Is it possible to sort out similar rows in a table and put the number in a column?

Tags: awk, table

I have this table

```
gene  5   5  5
gene  4   4  3
gene  5   5  5
gene  1   4  5
```

and I would like to have the following,

```
gene  5   5  5   2
gene  4   4  3   1
gene  1   4  5   1
```

so in the last column I would have a number of similar rows (in this case it's `gene 5 5 5`, that is present two times in the original table, while others presented only once).

What would be the best approach to do it? Is it a job for `awk`? Actually, is it even possible in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sort data.txt|uniq -c|sed -e 's/[ ]*\([0-9]\)   \(.*\)$/\2 \1/'|sort -nrk 5
gene  5   5  5   2
gene  4   4  3   1
gene  1   4  5   1
```